# Identifying this connector - PM395 thermal camera viewfinder

Tags: identification, connector, plug, thermal-camera

I have an old thermal camera (inframetrics PM395). I want to replace the original viewfinder with a small display. What is the name of this connector? I wish to make up my own cable using the same plug.

[image: connector]

[image: viewfinder]

Comment: It might be custom.

Comment: i know -- just figured i'd ask here too.

Comment: It looks like a Lemo push-pull connector.

Comment: As @LiorBilia stated, it could be a Lemo connector, but it appears to lack the locking system seen on those connectors. A [search on a distributor such as RS](https://au.rs-online.com/web/c/connectors/circular-connectors/industrial-circular-connectors/?pn=1&applied-dimensions=4294878611) may shed some light. Without connector dimensions, we can only eyeball many similar connectors.